# Creating a vector of sprites with SFML

Tags: c++, ubuntu, dynamic, sprite, sfml

I am trying to make a cloud throwing raindrops but I don't know how to dynamically create a vector of sprites with the texture of the raindrop. I'm trying this:

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite> shots(sf::Sprite(tex));

if(/*It has to rain*/){
    shots.push_back(new sf::Sprite(tex));
    sprite.setOrigin(15/2,20/2);
 }

for(i=0;i<shots.size;i++){
       window.draw(shots.at(i))
}
```

How should I create it?

Comment: You shouldn't put a `new sf::Sprite` into a `vector<sf::Sprite>`. Just put the object itself in there. Which version of SFML are you using?

Comment: Is that for an animation? If that's the case I think you overkilling by doing it with a vector